# Python program to calculate the years to double investment

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the program I've written to calculate the number of years it would take to double an initial investment, but it isn't working...

```
def main():

    x = eval(input("Enter initial investment: "))
    a = eval(input("Enter the annual interest rate: "))
    f = x * (1 + a)

    while f == 2 * x:
        t = x * 2 / x * (1 + a)
        print("The initial investment will double in",t)

main()
```

The program asks for the interest rate and principal, but then it stops. I have to use a while loop. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Remember what a "while" does. What you've written will check if f is equal to 2*x, which it almost certainly won't be the first time, and if it's not, it will stop, as you're seeing. That's the software problem

Also, I can't figure out just what you're doing to calculate the interest. Recheck the forumulas, and also are your trying to use compound or simple interest?

You want to compute the interest after x years each time inside the loop, and check THAT value against twice the principal. Also remember it may not exactly double in a number of years, it might be a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

def main():

```
invested = float(input("Please enter an inititial principal: "))
rate = float(input("Enter the annual interest rate: "))

year = 0
total = invested

while total <= invested * 2 :

    total = total + total * (rate)/100
    year = year + 1


print("Amount of time is ",year)
```

main()

Comment: this does not answer the question at all, should be a comment as suggestion or some kind of guideline